# Про́йденный или пройдённый?

Tags: орфоэпия

В который раз спотыкаюсь об это слово.
Толковый словарь Ушакова утверждает, что правильным написанием является **пройдённый**, а **прóйденный** — это чисто разговорная форма. Розенталь говорит, что единственная правильная форма — это **прóйденный**. Кто из них самый грамотный филолог?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый грамотный филолог – **это Грамота.ру**, там на первой же странице все ударения обозначены. Правильно: прОйденный, -ен, -ена, -ено, -ены.
Но мне вопрос показался  любопытным по своему содержанию, так как сам вызывает много вопросов.

1. **ПРОЙДЁННЫЙ**, пройдённая, пройдённое; пройдён, пройдена, пройдено, и (разг.). **ПРОЙДЕННЫЙ,** пройденная, пройденное; пройден, пройдена, Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.

Толковый словарь Ушакова написан давно,  а нормы  ударения могут со временем меняться, поэтому ударение надо проверять по самым новым источникам.

2. Но может это недавняя правка, можно ли доверять Грамоте. ру?  Нет, вот  у **Аванесова** (1987 год) форма пройдЁнный  уже названа **устаревшей.** Впрочем, такое же указание дается в словаре **Резниченко** (2010 год), а это значит, что устаревшая форма в языке еще применяется, хотя и является ненормированной.
3. Розенталь  орфоэпией вроде бы вплотную не  занимался,  надо давать ссылку на его высказывание. В общем, не надо бы сравнивать **Розенталя и Ушакова:**   в основном они работали  и в разное время, и  в разных областях языкознания.
4. А вот почему закрепилась и даже стала единственной разговорная форма ПРОЙДЕННЫЙ – **это вопрос**.  Новая форма отражается в языке, если приобретает бОльшую частотность.

Здесь можно даже высказать  собственное суждение.  Вероятно, такое ударение   было ближе пользователям. Мне кажется, что ударение на  первой части основы больше способствует пониманию  значения слова,  чем ударение на  суффиксе ЁНН, поэтому и выровнялись по ударению все формы слова.

Comment: Я бы оставил в употреблении _обе_ формы, отнеся вариант с "ё" к специфическим случаям - с акцентом на зависимые слова или на "факт прохождения": пройденный путь, но путь (или хлипкий мостик), _пройдённый_ над пропастью или со сломанной ногой (при каких обстоятельствах); "пройденная им война" = "та война, которую он прошёл", но "пройдённая им война = "то (тот факт), что он прошёл эту войну".

Comment: В случае "пройденного материала" или "длины пройденного пути" - однозначно "е". По моим ощущениям, вариант с "е" несёт оттенок "пройденного _когда-то_" и ставшего фактом прошлого, либо имеет количественный оттенок (вон _сколько_ и каких дорог исходил). Вероятно, в какой-то момент была проведена унификация, как в своё время в ведомстве Лопатина вышло с птичкой зорянкой (она не угодила безударностью корневого слога и превратилась в "зарянку").

Comment: Вероятно, оттенки значений существуют, но они неясно осознаются пользователями. Я просмотрела примеры из Нцкорпуса, но во всех случаях сделала бы ударение на приставке. Возможно, она обозначает границы пути: пройти расстояние от А до Б (количественное значение), но  и в других значениях уже закрепилась та же форма.

Comment: По поводу Розенталя - взято отсюда: https://www.labirint.ru/books/503907/
В орфографичесокм словаре указана единственная форма **прóйденный**.

Comment: @ Alex_ander Думаю, что унификация слова произошла в течение приблизительно 15–20 лет после словаря Ушакова. Из ОСРЯ (С. И. Ожегов и А. Б. Шапиро, 1957, 110 000 слов): **про́йденный**; _кр. ф._ -ен, -ена, -ено и **пройдённый**; _кр. ф._ -ён, -ена́, -ено́. P. S. Удивительно: словарь старше, чем я (есть еще и ОС проф. Д. Н. Ушакова, для начальной, неполной средней и средней школы, 1938 г. — мамин).

Comment: @ freim .Д.Э. Розенталь (1900 – 1994). В его прижизненных трудах нет специальных орфографических словарей, но, возможно, словарный материал  входил в различные справочники по правописанию. Но в любом случае все издания после 1994 года следует считать не оригинальными источниками, а переработанными и дополненными другими авторами. В частности, у меня есть двухтомник 2005 года, куда входит орфографический словарь, но там указан единственный вариант «прОйденный». Соответственно, вариант «пройдённый» в новых изданиях, скорее всего, ошибочный.

Answer (score 1):

> Толковый словарь Ушакова утверждает, что правильным написанием
> является **пройдённый**, а **прóйденный** — это чисто разговорная
> форма. Розенталь говорит, что единственная правильная форма — это
> **прóйденный**…

По-моему, **Розенталь** ОБЕ ФОРМЫ считал правильными.

См. [**Розенталь Дитмар Эльяшевич. Словарь трудностей русского языка** : Ок. 30000 слов / Д. Э. Розенталь, М. А. Теленкова. - 4-е изд., стер. - М. : Рус. яз., 1985]:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the user's attentiveness and the complexity of the environment, people may either look at the stair edges continuously, or they may glance down to scan the stair periodically. Research demonstrates that they scan at least once every seven steps taken (Templer, 1992).
В зависимости от внимательности использующего лестницу и сложности среды, люди могут или рассматривать края ступеней непрерывно, или они могут бросать взгляд периодически, вплоть до сканирования ступенек. Исследование демонстрирует, что они сканируют по крайней мере, один раз каждые семь пройденных ступеней   (Templer, 1992).
Мой перевод Word хочет исправить (обязательное применение ё).
По смыслу необходимо оставлять Ё. Поскольку мне скоро 70, думаю, употребление е вместо ё сформировалось не менее 60 лет назад.
Кстати, когда по смыслу  ё, также употребляю. Так что, думаю, первый комментатор прав.
Спасибо за справку.